# Question about button circuit

Tags: esp32, button

I'm quite a beginner at electronics, but thought I would try venture into it.
Currently I'm working on a project where I need to reuse a button module salvaged from some old hardware, but I can't figure out the wiring. The attached image is what I was able to track down on how the circuit is built. I'm not really sure how to wire it? Would it be possible to use this with an ESP32 and differentiate all the buttons?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the picture shows no resistors ... it also shows no circuitry ... please add a view of the back side of the board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Take a multimeter and measure the resistance between the left-most pin and each of the other pins with all the different combinations of button pairs pressed. Write down the results.

Then build a voltage divider for each output (Connect a resistor to ground on each output, and then connect that pin to an analog input on the Arduino. The resistor value to use will depend on the readings you get, but a 1K ohm resistor would be a good starting point.)

Then set up the 2 input pins on your Arduino as analog inputs and measure the voltage with no buttons, top button, bottom button, and both buttons pressed for each pair. Write those values down. Then write code that checks for voltages *roughly* equal to your measurements for each button press combo (You will need check for ranges of values, since the values will vary some.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick answer. So, am I commpletely wrong to assume it to be something like this? (:
https://imgur.com/a/q9uITj6

Comment: @Eyee The circuit on the image in your comment is exactly, what DuncanC described. From the analog input pins each a resistor to ground and a direct connection to the buttons output pin (in your schematics at the right). And the single pin on the left to Vcc (which is 3.3V in your case)

Comment: Yup, that looks about right. You might need to experiment with different resistor values. Like I said, a 1k  would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answers!

Comment: Do you know the value of R1 in your circuit diagrams? (The resistors that are in parallel with your switches?)

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried to measure it, but wasn't able to get a stable reading. The smd component is also blank, so couldn't look it up. The others were labled 102,101, 202 and 202. But I went ahead with your solution and everything works perfectly! Ty very much. Used a 10k ohm resistors for both and I'm able to distinguish the buttons with a rough analog read difference of 300, so it seems pretty stable for now.